# How to pass class object to another class that is using super();

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, program-entry-point

I have been working all day, so this may be a no brainer but my tired brain fails to see it. If that is the case, sorry for the stupid question. Now, to my problem.

I want my `Gui` class to have access to the class `Validator`. In the `main` class, which creates all classes, the `Gui` and `Validate` class is created.

Like this:

```
public class Main{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Gui gui = new Gui();
        Validate validate = new Validate();
    }   

}
```

Now, I want my Gui class to have access to Validate class and be able to access its methods.

Here is my Gui class constructor:

```
public class Gui extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

//A list of variables here...

public Gui(){

    super("BANK");

    //rest of the constructor.
```

Now, how do I let my `Gui` class access the `validate` while using the `super();` ?

Comment: While using the `super()`? This question is somewhat unclear.

Comment: If you control `GUI`, then you can either add a new constructor which accepts the `Validate` instance and calls `this()` first within it or supply a setter method which will allow you supply the instance of `Validate`...

Comment: You can hand the `Validate` in to your `Gui` constructor, but `super()` is the constructor for `JFrame`, so it won't know or care about `Validate`.

Comment: Thanks guys, i think i got it now. My brain is tired and fried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would try something like:

```
public class Gui extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
    private Validate validate;
    public Gui(Validate validate){
        super();
        this.validate = validate;
        //rest of the constructor.
    }
    ...
}

    public class Main{

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Validate validate = new Validate();
            Gui gui = new Gui(validate);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Oh, so it is possible to do that. I was unsure of if I could do that while using super(); Thanks. My brain is fried.

Answer (score 0):

You have no control from that class over what super does, so you either pass it to the constructor as an argument and save it on a variable or make validate static so everyone can access it (tho is not recomendable and you would only be able to have one instance of it).

```
public class Main{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Validate validate = new Validate();
        Gui gui = new Gui(validate);
    }   

}

public class Gui extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

//A list of variables here...
private Validate validate;

public Gui(Validate val){

    super("BANK");
    validate = val;

    //rest of the constructor.
}
```

This way Gui has a reference to validate and can access any public methods and variables.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean `super()` on this line `super("BANK");` , then you can't , this `super("BANK")` refers to `JFrame`'s constructor as your Gui class is extending JFrame. It only accept parameter for `String title` and/or `GraphicConfiguration gc`.

You need modify your constructor :

```
 private Validate validate;
 public Gui(Validate validate){
    super("BANK"); // this super refers to JFrame constructor
    this.validate = validate;

}
```